# "Ne pas pouvoir croire que" + subjonctif ?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

Est-ce qu'on emploie le subjonctif ou l'indicatif après ne pas pouvoir croire ? Par exemple :

> Je ne pouvais pas croire que cela soit/ est vrai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'indicatif est plus indiqué car l'action se situant dans le passé, on peut supposer qu'elle s'est réalisée.

> Je ne pouvais pas croire que cela était vrai. (que c'était vrai)

Le subjonctif, plus littéraire, peut être utilisé si le doute persiste :

> Je ne pouvais pas croire que ce[la] fût vrai.

Au présent, le subjonctif se rencontre dans la langue soignée :

> Je ne peux pas croire que ce[la] soit vrai.

Dans la langue courante, l'indicatif est cependant plus habituel :

> Je ne peux pas croire que c'est vrai.

Answer (score 0):

Apparemment, on ne devrait jamais employer le présent de l'indicatif, tout au moins dans le texte ; ce n'est jamais utilisé dans le [texte](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=croire+que+cela+soit+vrai%2Ccroire+que+cela+est+vrai.+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccroire%20que%20cela%20soit%20vrai%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccroire%20que%20cela%20soit%20vrai%3B%2Cc0).

Exemples récents

1/ Jean-Marie Fonteneau - 1994 - ‎Aperçu - ‎Autres éditions
... de temps à autre, le jardin, que personne ne parcourt plus, devient une forêt mycologique tellement inquiétante que je n'ose m'y aventurer. Lorsque devant soi on découvre un décor — je dis décor car je ne veux pas croire que cela soit vrai ...

2/ Les lingots d'or de Jean-Marie Le Pen cachés en Suisse
Tribune de Genève-28 avr. 2015
... et des explications de Jean-Marie Le Pen», a-t-il ensuite déclaré. «Je ne peux pas croire que cela soit vrai», a-t-il enfin ajouté sur ce sujet.

3/ Californie : une femme et ses deux arrière-petits-enfants périssent ...
Paris Match-30 juil. 2018
La famille qui vit en ville pleure ces trois âmes magnifiques, mon cœur est brisé, je n'arrive pas à croire que cela soit vrai, je n'arrête pas de voir ...

Dans ces exemples le premier verbe du couple  est au présent au lieu de l'imparfait ou c'est un autre verbe, comme  « vouloir » et « arriver » mais cela ne change rien.

Plus employé, l'[imparfait](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=croire+que+c%27%C3%A9tait+vrai&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccroire%20que%20c%27%C3%A9tait%20vrai%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccroire%20que%20c'%C3%A9tait%20vrai%3B%2Cc0) s'emploie aussi pour dire la même chose ;

- Je ne pouvais pas croire que c'était vrai.
- Je ne pouvais pas croire que cela était vrai. *rare*

Comment: Même si elle présente un problème de concordance de temps, la question porte sur le le mode, pas sur le temps à utiliser.