# How do you say “I’m still having to do your laundry.”?

Tags: traduction

**Scenario**:

Jake’s mother is fed up with his laziness.

**Dialogue**

Mom: Why is there so much dirty laundry?

Jake: Oh, sorry Mom. Most of that pile is mine.

Mom: Well then you do the laundry.

Jake: I can’t Mom. I’m busy.

Mom: Jake! You’re 24! I can’t believe that after all these years, I’m still having to do your laundry!

**Question**

How do you say ”I can’t believe that after all these years, I’m still having to do your laundry!”?

I’m struggling to translate “*I’m still having to do your laundry*.”

**Answer**

Is it

(a) « Je ne peux pas croire qu’après toutes ces années, *je fais toujours ta lessive*. »

or

(b) « Je ne peux pas croire qu’après toutes ces années, *je dois toujours faire ta lessive.* »

or something else?

Comment: When you say *je fais toujours ta lessive* you don't translate "I have to". *Je fais ta lessive* → I do your laundry. *Je dois faire ta lessive* →I have to do your laundry. [Have to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/have-to) can be found in any dictionary.  Some people would use the subjunctive after *je ne peux pas croire*, this has [already been discussed on FL](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/36888/358).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say *je fais toujours ta lessive* you don't translate "I have to", you're just saying "I'm still doing your laundry", so of the two sentences you have in mind only (b) is correct. But still, I would not spontaneously say it like that.

1. I expect most people would spontaneously say *encore* and not *toujours*. *Toujours* might imply frequency (Mum complaining of having to do the laundry too often), *encore* stresses the fact that mum thinks she shouldn't have to do Jake's laundry at all.
2. Although *devoir* is correct, French often uses the Gallicism *il faut que* (*falloir*) to express necessity/obligation.
3. With *je ne peux pas croire* in the main clause, a lot of people would use the subjonctive in the subordinate:  *Je ne peux pas croire qu’après toutes ces années, je doive encore faire ta lessive*, but the subjunctive is not mandatory.
4. If you use *il faut que*, be aware that the subjunctive is mandatory after *il faut que*: *Je ne peux pas croire qu’après toutes ces années, il faut encore que je fasse ta lessive*.

Comment: Your answer is very clear and I have learnt a lot! Thank you @None !

Answer (score 3):

*J'y crois pas, tu as 24 ans et c'est moi qui dois encore me taper ta lessive !*

Comment: ou : t'es pas fichu de faire ta lessive toi-même.

Comment: _Qui doiS?_ J'aurais mis un _s_.

Comment: @Frank Oui, bien sûr. C'est *nous* qui *doivent* faire attention ;-)

Comment: Thank you @jlliagre once again for your help! :)